# Rails : Couldn't find Item with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to implement add to favorites and I'm getting this error:

```
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in FavoriteItemsController#index
 Couldn't find Item with 'id'=
```

this is where the error pops up, at the following link:

```
<%= link_to "Favorite Items", favorites_path, method: :get, :class => 'navbar-link'  %>
```

model associations

```
class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :viewer
  belongs_to :favorited, polymorphic: true
end

class Viewer < ApplicationRecord
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
 :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

has_many :favorites
has_many :favorite_items, through: :favorites, source: :favorited, source_type: 'Item'
end
```

routes:

```
get '/favorites', to: 'favorite_items#index', as: 'favorites'
resources :favorite_items, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

and the `add` or `remove` favorites links on my show page:

```
<%- unless current_shopper.favorite_items.exists?(id: @item.id) -%>
    <%= link_to 'Add to favorites', favorite_items_path(item_id: @item), method: :post %>
<%- else -%>
    <%= link_to 'Remove from favorites', favorite_item_path(@item), method: :delete %>
<%- end -%>
```

the controller

```
class FavoriteItemsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_item

  def index
   @favorites = current_viewer.favorites
  end

  def create
    if Favorite.create(favorited: @item, viewer: current_viewer)
      redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item has been favorited'
    else
      redirect_to @item, alert: 'Something went wrong...*sad panda*'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    Favorite.where(favorited_id: @item.id, viewer_id: current_viewer.id).first.destroy
    redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item is no longer in favorites'
  end

  private

  def set_item
    @item = Item.find(params[:item_id] || params[:id])
  end
```

and the index to loop thru the favored items, although not sure if this is correct since the error stops before the loop:

```
 <% @favorites.each do |item| %>
    <tr>
     <td><%= item.title %></td>
     <td><%= item.price %></td>
     <td><%= link_to 'Remove from favorites', favorite_items_path(@item.id), method: :delete %></td>
  <  /tr>
 <% end %>
```

**Update 1**

This is what I get when I click on add to favorites

```
Item Exists (4.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "items" INNER JOIN "favorites" 
ON "items"."id" = "favorites"."favorited_id" WHERE "favorites"."viewer_id"
 = $1 AND "favorites"."favorited_type" = $2 AND "items"."id" = $3 LIMIT $4 
 [["viewer_id", 2], ["favorited_type", "Item"], ["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

items_controller.rb

```
def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


def show
  @comments = Comment.where(item_id: @item).order("created_at DESC")
  @items = Item.find(params[:id]) 
end
```

Comment: Can you confirm that @item is not nil?

Comment: add or remove favorites links on my show page:   where is your show action  ?

Comment: @krishnar... Show action is in the `items_controller.rb`  and this is in it`@items = Item.find(params[:id])`

Comment: can u update your question with items controller.And where you're setting \@item in item controller?

Comment: Also please check update 1 for more info.

Comment: @ krishnar I just added the `items_controller.rb`

Comment: before_action :set_item, only: [:create, :destroy]    try this

Comment: It works, but now I get an error at this line in the `index.html.erb` `<%= link_to 'Remove from favorites', favorite_items_path(@item.id), method: :delete %>` the error is `undefined method id' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: favorite_items_path(item.id)      use item.id

Comment: when I click on the remove favorite I get : `Routing Error` `No route matches [DELETE] "/favorite_items.2"`

Comment: use this   favorite_item_path(item.id)

Comment: Thanks @krishnar it works now!!!

Comment: accept and upvote my answer. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class FavoriteItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_item, only: [:create, :destroy]
  ..
  ..
end
```

**Index html**

> <%= link_to 'Remove from favorites',
>   favorite_items_path(@item.id), method: :delete %>

replace with

> <%= link_to 'Remove from favorites', favorite_item_path(item.id),
>   method: :delete %>

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing you `FavoriteItemsController` with

```
before_action :set_item, :only => [:create, :destroy]
```

Comment: It works, but now I get an error at this line in the `index.html.erb` `<%= link_to 'Remove from favorites', favorite_items_path(@item.id), method: :delete %>` the error is `undefined method id' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: use `item.id`  instead of `@item.id`